# Domain mapping WP

Tags: wordpress

I have created a sub domain that has main wp site. wp.domain.com

I have created 2 sites in WP:
1. wp.domain.com
2. wp2.domain.com

"wp2.domain.com" has to be mapped to domain2.com/blog

Domain2.com is pointed to my server
And i have virtual host entry below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName domain2.com
        ServerAlias www.domain2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Domain was successfully added to the WP
Site ID: 2
Domain: domain2.com/blog

When I access "domain2.com/blog" nothing happens.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

ServerName Should be the subdomian like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName sub.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: why domain2 should have "sub."? ive tried adding this without much luck

Comment: sub is example , in your case should be wp. or wp2.

Comment: what if i have folders, is their a work around it? domain1.com/blog/blog2 has to be accessed at domain2.com/blog?

Comment: you can put your folder path what ever it is